# Both forms of future continuous in the same sentence

Tags: future, continuous-aspect

I did an online quiz and I wish someone to tell me why my answer was reported to be incorrect. In the sentence below, I selected "She is going to be preparing dinner" but apparently the correct answer was "She will be preparing dinner".

Sentence:

*Tomorrow at this time, they will also be doing the same thing. She is **going to be preparing dinner** and he is going to be reading. They are very predictable people!*

Source: [englishpage.com](http://www.englishpage.com/verbpage/verbs30finaltest.htm)

Comment: I would not call your choice incorrect, but consider that the first sentence uses *will*.

Comment: The error you made was to do that particular online quiz.

Answer (score 1):

Not only is your version also correct, I suggest it may be more suitable.

*She will be preparing dinner* is a simple statement about the future, whereas *She is going to be preparing dinner* has the more specific meaning (as required in your test question), that at some known time in the future, an action will be occurring in the present, and there is a high level of confidence about its happening.

This is a subtly different way of expressing the concept, and its use depends on the context.

You would not wish to use it unnecessarily, since it is longer and potentially inelegant, however *By late morning we're going to be lazing on the beach* says something additional, and is not quite as straightforward as *Later this morning we'll be lazing on the beach.*